# How to get the device location in intentService ?

Tags: android, location

i have alarm that calls my intentService every 15 min, in the intentService how could i get the device location? (note: i have a wakeLock in my intentService)

Comment: Why do you need this..do you want to keep polling the location to find out whether you have a particular location or you want to track the users location every 15mins??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are welcome to try `getLastKnownLocation()`, but it is likely that it will be `null`. And an `IntentService` cannot wait around for some location fix to arrive.

Rather, you need a regular `Service`, crafted to handle this scenario. I created one ([`LocationPoller`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll)), which [another developer has improved upon](https://github.com/alexbirkett/cwac-locpoll).